# Haskell : error while declaring new type

Tags: haskell

I Have defined new type in file `file.hs`

```
module FunctorChapter
  (
  FixMePls
  )
  where
  data FixMePls a =
    Fixme | Pls a
    deriving (Show,Eq)
```

when imported the `file.hs` into ghci it is loaded successfully but I am not able to use the constructor `Pls`

```
Main File> Pls "test"
<interactive>:5:1: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Pls’
```

while I can use the Just constructor

```
Main File> Just "me"
Just "me"
```

what is missing in my type?

Comment: It still works for me.

Comment: have you used also `module () where`?

Comment: Your file name should match the module name - i.e. module `FunctorChapter` should reside in file `FunctorChapter.hs`.

Comment: OP: Yes I have. @ErikR It works even for differently named modules for me.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the `FunctorChapter` module loaded, but some different `File` module.

Comment: what I meant by file is my file name , moreover  I am using stack so all what  I did is to use `stack ghci` to test the code, and I have recognized something is when I use :load `functorChapter` it works but when I use `stack ghci` it doesn't

Comment: Note the prompt: it says `Main File>`. This shows that `FunctorChapter` isn't loaded. "when I use :load functorChapter it works but when I use stack ghci it doesn't" After running `stack ghci`, you still need to load the modules, see https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#ghci-the-repl.